# Wrap functions automatically in PHP Designer 8

Tags: php, phpdesigner

As I start to work in OOP's, I build a lot of classes and functions and I'd love to wrap each function automatically and expand when I like.

Is that possible with PHP Designer 8. I am a jEdit user, does PHP Designer supports it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question in the title is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is NO... PHPDesigner does not support selective wrapping of code till atleast version 8.1...
This sheet would provide you feature comprision between PHP editors

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Agccij5yGAXacFY4WHlVU1VPTTdFVDA3cm40bjdOWUE#gid=0

What <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> gets you is wordwrap which you would get even in notepad(without ++)...